# Dictionaries in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to input a dictionary of tuples.

I want the output to look like:  `{1: (a, b,c), 2: (d, e, f)}`

Currently it looks like: `{1: (a, ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c'), 2: ('d', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'f')}`

```py
a={}
n=int(input("Number of elements: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    key=int(input("Enter key: "))
    value=input("Enter value: ")
    tup=tuple(value)
    a[key]=tup
```

Comment: what do you input as value?

Comment: are those strings? Currently this gives me NameError because you use variables that are not in use yet (with exception of `a` with is a dict) ... most probably you want `tup=tuple(value.split())`

Comment: Please mention the input??

Comment: What result do you expect for the input ``1`` ``ab cd`` ``2`` ``d e fg``?

Comment: in case of key - integers 1,2...

Comment: and string for values

Comment: please attach exact input  you enter at cmd terminal

Comment: Number of elements: 2
Enter key: 1  
Enter value: a b c
Enter key: 2
Enter value: d e f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are casting strings separated by spaces to tuple... try to use split methud before:

```
a={}
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    key=int(input("Enter key: "))
    value=input("Enter value: ")
    tup=tuple(value.split())
    a[key]=tup
...
Enter value:
>>>a b c 
Enter key:
>>>2 
Enter value:
>>>d e f
{1: ('a', 'b','c'), 2: ('d', 'e', 'f')}
```

if you want to print it without quotes you can just turn it into string and eliminate the quotes:

```
import json
str_a = json.dumps(a).replace('"','').replace("'",'')
# or ass suggested in the comments two lines by @Axe319: 
# foo = lambda x: f"({', '.join(x)})" 
# print('{' + (', '.join(f'{k}: {foo(v)}' for k, v in a.items())) + '}')
print(str_a)
>>>'{1: (a, b, c), 2: (d, e, f)}'
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to get to output - {1: (a, b, c), 2: (d, e, f)}

Comment: Dictionary values with out single quotes.

The current output looks - {1: ('a', 'b', 'c'), 2: ('d', 'e', 'f')}

Comment: Oh let me check this one second

Comment: Another option as a two-liner. `foo = lambda x: f"({', '.join(x)})"`  `print('{' + (', '.join(f'{k}: {foo(v)}' for k, v in a.items())) + '}')`

Comment: thanks added it... saves you from using json module!

Answer (score 0):

in your code, modify

```
tup=tuple(value)
```

to be

```
tup = tuple(value.split(','))
```

and it will give your expected results.

```
a = {}
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    key = int(input("Enter key: "))
    value = input("Enter value: ")
    tup = tuple(value.split(','))
    a[key] = tup

print(a)

'''
The input:
2
Enter key: 1
Enter value: a,b,c
Enter key: 2
Enter value: d,e,f
{1: ('a', 'b', 'c'), 2: ('d', 'e', 'f')}
'''
```

Comment: Thanks.
But is there a way to get to make the output look : {1: (a, b, c), 2: (d, e, f)}